# Push Notification When App is closed/Quit including

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

Can anyone please so let me know precisely that how can I accomplish the task in which I need to show Push Notification to user when App is Quit/closed?

Currently, I am able to get the push notification done when App is running in background or opened. But App couldn't receive Notification when it is quit/closed by the user.

Right now, it's a really critical task on my shoulders. It's pretty clear do tell me in case if you guys need me to brief in details.

Comment: It's actually not clear at all. Is this iOS or Android or both? What is your full Worklight version and build number? What do you mean by "app couldn't receive notification when it is quit/closed"? Do you mean that the notification arrives to the device but when opening the app it is not shown? In that case, mention that. Then also mention how do you open the app when the notification arrives, by tapping the notification in the notification bar/area or tapping the app icon? Then I may have additional questions/requests for you.

Comment: Thanks for your concern Idan;
1) I am doing it for Android
2) using IBM MobileFirst v7
3) Push Notification is working, when app is running in background. I am able to receive Notification using ChallengeHandler.js (traditional Code) and opening fine in App
4) Objective is when I QUIT/close the APP, it doesn't receive notifications.

Comment: Okay. I am asking though when does it Not work. I gave two scenarios. Which?

Comment: Terry, what does not receive the notification? The notification first arrives to the OS and displayed in the notification area. Then you can either tap the notification or the app icon. Does the notification arrive to the device? If yes, what do you do next?

Comment: both scenarios are working fine. In addition, when I close the app(or kill the process) then app not receiving push notifications.

Comment: So: when the app is open, you receive the notification in the app. When the app is open and in the background you receive the notification in the device and can bring the app to the foreground via the notification area or the app icon and see the notification. If the app is quit (not running), the notification does not arrive to the device at all?

Comment: Yes you perfectly getting me Idan... Please, suggest me the solution. I would be pleased dear

Comment: @Terry until unless you "Force stop " your application in the Android device you will be able to get the notification . Lets say that you are closing the applcation at that time are you logout the user ?

Comment: @KawineshSK- yes Man my app logouts with the user. and whenever i open my app it registers to subscribe again with the same name again.
Can you please guide me what i can do with best practices that when my App closed/quite I could be able to receive Push messages :(

Answer (score 0):

I am having a very hard time to believe that your scenario is Really the following:

1. When the app is either: open and in the foreground, or open and in the background, you are able to receive a notification to the device, and have its contents displayed in the app, but
2. When the app is quit (as in not running), the notification does not arrive to the device at all.

I have tested several devices and several push-enabled applications (event source, tag-based). The notification does arrive to the device, after the user subscribed to either a tag or by logging-in (in the case of event source-based), after which sending a notification always arrived to the device.

I don't understand this sentence:

> my app logouts with the user

You need to be CLEAR in your explanation. Is there a logout button that the user clicks? If yes, are you also for some reason perform an unsubscribe API invocation? If no, edit the question and provide DETAILED, step-by-step reproduction instructions, AS WELL as provide your application, or any code that you use so that it could be inspected for possible issues.

Comment: Idan- I got completely your point. Now let me tell you the solution:
The code was right what it is. what we have to do is to enable the NOTIFICATION option using setting in Android. IT WORK's, it all it takes.

Appreciate your help guys! I mean it thanks